# Array.pop Race Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, concurrency, locking, race-condition

3 users on the system simultaneously click buy ticket.

**model**

```
class TicketInventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :ticket_roll, Array
end
```

ticket_roll is seeded with a range of numbers

**controller**

```
ticket_inventory = TicketInventory.find(1)
ticket_roll = ticket_inventory.ticket_roll
TicketInventory.transaction do
  @ticket = ticket_roll.pop
  ticket_inventory.save
end
```

They all get the same ticket.

I have contemplated `lock_version`, but that would raise an error instead of providing the next ticket.

I also looked at Indexes, but that would require a row per ticket.

How to avoid this race condition?

Comment: If you use optimistic locking (ie lock_version) you just need to rescue the error and retry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to use [ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html). It uses transaction and database lock. It is supported by PostgreSQL and MySQL according to documentation:

```
MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html
PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE
```

You can use it in this way:

```
ticket_inventory = TicketInventory.find(1)
ticket_inventory.with_lock do
  ticket_roll = ticket_inventory.ticket_roll
  @ticket = ticket_roll.pop
  ticket_inventory.save
end
```

Try it, it could probably work.

Comment: Was about to write this up